# Using JOIN to display data in a table

Tags: php, join, mysqli

Thanks for reading my question

i am trying to make *clients_id* from the table **repair_jobs** appear as the *name* from the table **contacts**

but i am having no luck
i have got 2 sql query's is this wrong?

the 1st

```
$query = "select * from repair_jobs";
```

this helps me display the information i need regarding the fields from repair_jobs and works

this is the 2nd

```
$query = "SELECT repair_jobs.client_id, contacts.name
FROM repair_jobs
INNER JOIN contacts
ON repair_jobs.client_id=contacts.name";
```

under that i have this to try to display the name of the client

```
echo "<td>{$client_id}</td>";
```

but it is only displaying the number and not the data (clients name) that i need

am i missing something?

---

### Additional information

The client_id (repair_jobs) is a number and is the same as id (contacts) but wanting to display the name (contacts)

**CLIENTS**

```
Id – name – surname – phone – address
```

**REPAIRS**

```
Id – clients_id (same as id in clients) – unit – date – price
```

---

### current code

```
<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

//query all records from the database
$query = "select * from repair_jobs";

//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

//get number of rows returned
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

//this will link us to our add.php to create new record
if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database record

    //start table
    //creating our table heading
    echo " <table class='table_basic'>";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
        echo "<th>Job #</th>";
        echo "<th>Name Of Unit</th>";
        echo "<th>Client</th>";
        echo "<th>Estimated Value</th>";
    echo "</thead></tr><tbody><tr>";

    //loop to show each records
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td width='40px'><a href='rdetails.php?id={$id}'># {$id}</a></td>";
                echo "<td>{$rmake} {$rmodel}</td>";

$query = "SELECT rj.client_id, c.name AS client_name FROM repair_jobs rj INNER JOIN contacts c ON rj.client_id=c.id";
echo "<td>{$client_name}</td>";

echo '<td align="center"><span class="badge badge-success">£';
$lhours = $labour;
$repaircosts = $ourcosts;
$labourpay = $labourcharge;
$sum_total = $repaircosts +($lhours * $labourpay);




print ($sum_total);
echo '</span></td>';
echo "</td>";
echo "";
    }

    echo "</tr></table>";//end table

}else{
    //if database table is empty
    echo "No records found.";
}

//disconnect from database
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: We'll need to see the schema for the tables. Does `contacts.name` actually equal to `repair_jobs.client_id`? Or is there a `contacts.id` that might be more appropriate?

Comment: the two rows are named client_id (in the repair_jobs table) and name (in the contacts table)

Comment: That was not the question. Is this client_id actually an ID, or is it the name of the contact? Is this contacts.name and ID, or is it the name of the contact? If the answer to both questions isn't the same, you're doing something wrong by joining on the wrong criteria. And if they _are_ the same, you're still doing something wrong because your naming scheme sucks.

Comment: sorry client_id is a number and name is the name of the client

Comment: i have updated my question with additional information of what you might be asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your 1st query to you join query, as there is no reason to do a 2nd query in the middle of your code. (also you never executed that query anyway).

```
//query all records from the database
$query = "SELECT repair_jobs.*, contacts.name as client_name
FROM repair_jobs
INNER JOIN contacts
ON repair_jobs.client_id=contacts.id";
```

Then in your table keep the `$client_name`

```
echo "<td>{$client_name}</td>";
```

Comment: He stated he wanted the client *name* to appear there. **but it is only displaying the number and not the data (clients name) that i need
**

Comment: See my updated answer. Just use your join query as your 1st query.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';
$query = "SELECT rj.Id AS job_number, rj.unit, rj.make, rj.model, c.name AS client_name, rj.price FROM repair_jobs rj INNER JOIN contacts c ON rj.clients_id = c.id ORDER BY c.date";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );
$num_results = $result->num_rows;
if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database record
    echo " <table class='table_basic'>";
    echo "<thead><tr>";
    echo "<th>Job #</th>";
    echo "<th>Name Of Unit</th>";
    echo "<th>Client</th>";
    echo "<th>Estimated Value</th>";
    echo "</tr></thead><tbody>";
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
        extract($row);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td width='40px'><a href='rdetails.php?id={$job_number}'>#{$job_number}</a></td>";
        echo "<td>{$make} {$model}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$client_name}</td>";
        echo "<td align='center'><span class='badge badge-success'>£";
        $lhours = $labour;
        $repaircosts = $ourcosts;
        $labourpay = $labourcharge;
        $sum_total = $repaircosts +($lhours * $labourpay);
        echo $sum_total;
        echo '</span></td>';
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
} else {
    echo "No records found.";
}
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: What are you using to fetch the rows?

Comment: thx for your help but now i am getting syntax error on that code

Comment: @DevlshOne The OP is using `mysqli` object oriented style, so it does not make sense to use `mysql` procedural style code/examples

Comment: Here's an all new set of code for you... I've never used `extract`, so you'll have to double check me on those. And the `rmake` and `rmodel` fields were never mentioned in your **repair_jobs** table before. So, it may need some tweaking but it is error free.